# Is it possible to hide some logs on a Java application that works with IBM Datastage?

Tags: java, mongodb, datastage

on my java application that connects to IBM Datastage, i'm using the logger in the IBM libraries com.ibm.is.cc.javastage.api for my logging purposes. I've been asked by the client to clean the log up a bit, removing the repeating mongodb cluster warning logs, those that look like this:

```
Java_InsSQLServer4,5: [cluster-ClusterId...INFO org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened 
     connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:50197}] to ...
```

But there doesn't seem to be any method (like for example, getLogger() from the default java Logger) that lets me do this. Is there any way to achieve this when working with datastage? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on where the logs appear and where they should be hidden from. If we're talking about the job log within DataStage, you could use a `Message Handler` to demote explicit log message types from warnings to information or suppress them entirely.

Comment: @JustusKenklies the logs appear on the java console, and thus also appear on the datastage log. I can't use message handler because the client wants us to remove them software-side.